# lcd "random fruit" built in function for pic

Tags: pic, c, lcd, programming

I'm trying to display a random fruit on an lcd and I was wondering if there's a built in function in the MikroC PRO for pic v.6.4.0 library that does so.

I drew the fruit using the lcd custom character tool and I'm using the generate code option.I would really appreciate your help. Here's the generated code:

```
 void fruit1(char pos_row, char pos_char) {
  char i;
    Lcd_Cmd(64);
    for (i = 0; i<=7; i++) Lcd_Chr_CP(fruit[i]);
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_RETURN_HOME);
    Lcd_Chr(pos_row, pos_char, 0);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to me that drawing random fruit would be a very common function in a standard library.  Also, is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You need a random number.

That's what the STDLIB `rand()` is for.

> Function returns a sequence of pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 32767. The function will always produce the same sequence of numbers unless srand is called to seed the start point.

Divide the result of `result = rand()` by the number of fruit you have to bring it down to a smaller range.

Then just use that number.

```
 if (result <= 30) then fruit1();
 else if (result <= 60) then fruit2();
 etc.
```

Use `srand()` to change the random number seed, or you will get the same set of "*random*" numbers eventually.